# Как определить четность/нечетность в sql запросе?

Tags: sql

Как определить четность/нечетность в sql запросе?

Answer (score 4):

> [MOD(N,M)](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Mathematical_functions.html)
> %
> Значение по модулю (подобно оператору % в C). Возвращает остаток от деления N на M

[MySQL четное/нечетное](http://tormix.com/index.php?do=art&art=28&s=Mysql_chetnoe_nechetnoe_).

Answer (score 4):

Для MSSQL & PostgreSQL так (Х - целое, проверяемое значение):

```
select case X % 2 when 0 then 'четное' else 'нечетное' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из самых простых способов определения нечетности числа в SQL запросах — это использование оператора "WHERE" с модулем. В этом случае, для определения нечетности числа, мы используем оператор "%" - этот оператор возвращает остаток от деления двух чисел в совокупности с "<>" - неравно 0 или  "=" равно 1.

Вот пример запроса, который возвращает только нечетные числа:

```sql
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE (column_name % 2) <> 0;
```

или

```sql
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE (column_name % 2) = 1;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Здравствуйте, понял, принял, обновил